# Sorting singly circular linked list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, circular-list

I'm trying to sort the singly circular linked list after each edit. But my code doesn't work. I based it on the selection sort algorithm. I've been doing this for hours but can't seem to get the correct code.

```
void editList(node *head, int value, int newValue)
{
    node *traverser = head;
    do {
        traverser = traverser -> next;
    }while(traverser -> data != value);

    traverser -> data = newValue;

    node *index;
    node *selection;
    node *temp = new node;

    for(index = head; index -> next != head; index = index -> next) {

        for(selection = head; selection -> next != head; selection = selection -> next) {
            if(index -> data > selection -> data) {
                temp -> data = index-> data;
                index -> data = selection -> data;
                selection -> data = temp -> data;

            }
        }//End of outer loop

    }//End of sorting

    return;
}//End of editList()
```

Comment: Assuming the list starts off sorted, since only one node is editted at at time, why not remove the node from the list, then re-insert it back into the list in it's proper location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When analyzing the provided source code, the proposed sort algorithm is very close to the expected **'selection sort algorithm'**.

The two nested loop are present, but doing independent features.

**Step 1** - performing a true nested loop by including condition from the first into the second loop.

> To sort all the list, the selection starts from the next node of the
>   index.

```
for(index = head; index -> next != head; index = index -> next) {
    // start the selection from the index->next
    for(selection = index->next; selection -> next != head; selection = selection -> next) {
        if(index -> data > selection -> data) {
            temp -> data = index-> data;
            index -> data = selection -> data;
            selection -> data = temp -> data;

        }
    }//End of outer loop
}//End of sorting
```

**Bonus 1** - because the swap is only performed at the `data` level, instead of using a temporary node, just use a integer.

```
// use just an integer
int temp;
...
temp = index-> data;
index -> data = selection -> data;
selection -> data = temp;
```

Instead of:

```
// allocated but never freed
node *temp = new node;
...
temp -> data = index-> data;
index -> data = selection -> data;
selection -> data = temp -> data;
```

**Bonus 2** - for the first search part to localize the node having the `int value` to be replaced, why not using the same loop structure to prevent a never-ending loop if no node has the searched value.

```
node *traverser;
// a ending loop to search a value into a circular-list
for(traverser = head; traverser->next != head; traverser = traverser -> next) {
    if (traverser -> data == value) {
        traverser -> data = newValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of

```
node *traverser = head;
do {
    traverser = traverser -> next;
}while(traverser -> data != value);

traverser -> data = newValue;
```